# PHP looping statement

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Upon applying this code: `$lines = explode("\n", $val);` where `$val = $_POST['result'];` and `$_POST['result'];` is from a textarea where these strings are being exploded:

> A - B -> 1:00
>
> B - A -> 1:30

So `$lines[0] = "A - B -> 1:00"` and `$lines[1] = "B - A -> 1:30"` respectively.

In `foreach ($lines as $line)` , I'll explode it again for every `->` meet. Like this:

```
    $fields = explode('->', $line);
    $loc = trim($fields[0]);
    $bltime = trim($fields[1]);
```

So `$loc`= "A - B" and `$bltime` = "1:00". Then I'll save these values in a table along with a value I stored in a session namely `$_SESSION[rno]` which is a primary key from another table and fetch another value from the same table.

```
    $e=mysql_query("select etd from reservation 
      where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $f=mysql_fetch_array($e);
    $g=$f['etd'];
    mysql_query("insert into pdf(reservno, block, location, etd) 
      values ('$_SESSION[rno]', '".mysql_escape_string($bltime)."','".
      mysql_escape_string($loc)."', '$g')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Then I need to add the values of `etd` and `block` for the value of `eta` then just update the table having the maximum `pdf_id` which is the primary key of `pdf` table after.

```
    $a=mysql_query("select pdf_id as 'maxpdf' from pdf where pdf_id in 
      (select max(pdf_id) from pdf where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]')") 
      or die(mysql_error());
    $b=mysql_fetch_array($a);
    $c=$b['maxpdf'];
    $h=mysql_query("select addtime(etd, block) as 'eta' from pdf 
      where pdf_id = '$c'") or die(mysql_error());
    $j=mysql_fetch_array($h);
    $k=$j['eta'];
    mysql_query("update pdf set eta = '$k' where pdf_id = '$c'") 
      or die(mysql_error());
```

So I'll have the following values in the `pdf` table upon running the whole codes I posted above still based on the above value of `$_POST['result'];`:

[image]

What I want to do is to make this possible: have the first computed `eta` the value of the next `etd` then compute for it's `eta` (`etd` + `block`). And then the `waiting` column should have the value of first `eta` minus the next `etd`. Something like this:

[image]

What is crucial and important here is the passing of the first `eta` to the next `etd` and the computation. How can I get it done when I'm required to loop through the exploded values? Please help me. I'm sorry for the long explanation but I want all of you to understand what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: **note** the deprecation process of `mysql_*` has been started. use [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: the table you have drawn is "reservation or PDF"??

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR, the first table is table PDF. The 2nd one is what I want table PDF to look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to pass the 1st `eta` value to the 2nd `etd` and so on. Here's the whole looping statement I used..

```
$lines = explode("\n", $val);

foreach ($lines as $line) 
{
    $fields = explode('->', $line);
    $loc = trim($fields[0]);
    $bltime = trim($fields[1]);
    $e=mysql_query("select eta as 'etd' from pdf where pdf_id in (select max(pdf_id) from pdf where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]')") or die(mysql_error());
    $f=mysql_fetch_array($e);
    $g=$f['etd'];
    if(empty($g))
    {
    $m=mysql_query("select etd from reservation where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $o=mysql_fetch_array($m);
    $p=$o['etd'];
    $temp=$p;
    }
    else
    {
    $temp=$g;
    }
    mysql_query("insert into pdf(reservno, block, location, etd) values ('$_SESSION[rno]', '".mysql_escape_string($bltime)."','".mysql_escape_string($loc)."', '$temp')") or die(mysql_error());
    $a=mysql_query("select pdf_id as 'maxpdf' from pdf where pdf_id in (select max(pdf_id) from pdf where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]')") or die(mysql_error());
    $b=mysql_fetch_array($a);
    $c=$b['maxpdf'];
    $h=mysql_query("select addtime(etd, block) as 'eta' from pdf where pdf_id = '$c'") or die(mysql_error());
    $j=mysql_fetch_array($h);
    $k=$j['eta'];
    mysql_query("update pdf set eta = '$k' where pdf_id = '$c'") or die(mysql_error());

}
```

The `if(empty($g))` statement checks if the query `select eta as 'etd' from pdf where pdf_id in (select max(pdf_id) from pdf where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]')` results an empty set or not. If the query results empty, then it is the first data to be inserted, therefore, `$temp` will hold the value of the resulted query `select etd from reservation where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]'`. If otherwise, it means that there's already data that was inputted beforehand so the `$temp` variable will hold the resulted query which is held by `$g`, so simply, `$temp = $g`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Where you insert into PDF, Before Inserting into PDF,

1) Get the Maximum Pdf_Id record, (i.e. the last inserted record)
2) Select the eta from this record and save it in a variable.
3) While inserting, insert the etd as the recorded variable.
```

That's it.

Edit your code like,

Instead of the following code,

```
  $e=mysql_query("select etd from reservation 
      where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $f=mysql_fetch_array($e);
    $g=$f['etd'];
```

Use, this replacement

```
   $NextETD = "Some Dfault Value, you may set it to 12:00";
   $a=mysql_query("select * from pdf where pdf_id in 
      (select max(pdf_id) from pdf where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]')") 
      or die(mysql_error());
    $b=mysql_fetch_array($a);
    $LastETA=$b['eta'];
    if($LastETA!=null){
        $NextETD = $LastETA;
    }
   mysql_query("insert into pdf(reservno, block, location, etd) 
      values ('$_SESSION[rno]', '".mysql_escape_string($bltime)."','".
      mysql_escape_string($loc)."', '$NextETD')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: How can I make it work inside the looping statement? Please see edited. Thanks.

Comment: Before the first inert statement, just make sure you check that at least one record is returned

Comment: I should insert the first eta from the query `select etd from reservation where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]'`.  If that query is under the loop statement, how can I change the 2nd etd? I'm sorry for my lacking but I don't get it that much.

Comment: Assuming the table with no records, on the first ietration you would get the value of eta as null. You shall make a check,

if ($eta !=null) {
 $etd = $eta
}

Comment: Can I set the default value from a result of this query: `select etd from reservation where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]'`?

Comment: That;s good, it helped. Would you mark this as an answer and upvote it.